# "'mongoimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command" when creating db using mongojs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How to create DB, using mongojs?
I tried to run command, but there are errors...

```
var db = require('mongojs').connect('learn', ['mikecollection']),
    mycollection = db.collection('mikecollection'),
    query_results,
    data = require('./data.json'),
    sys = require('sys');

var util = require('util'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('mongoimport --db mikeDB --collection mycol --file "A:\Users\Mike\Desktop\nodejs\2_temp\data.json"',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
      console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
      if (error !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + error);
      }
  });
```

Error:

```
Error: Command failed: 'mongoimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command –
```

Comment: Error: Command failed: 'mongoimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: `mongoimport` is bundled with the rest of mongodb. You either don't have your PATH set up correctly or you haven't installed mongodb at all.

Comment: exec will run in a special envo, PATH will not work, you must directly reference the program in its location

Comment: I copy the mongoimport.exe into program directory, and change command-argument: mongoimport --db pigDB --collection mycol --file data.json. And it work...but I think it isn't good idea and not optimal decision...Can You suggest me module, which can create DB in MongoDB?

Comment: You could use mongoose (http://mongoosejs.com/) to generate your schema and handles your schema as an ORM